Fetch many emails with Gmail API fast
I'm trying to fetch multiple emails quickly using the Gmail API with the following function:
def get_mails(self, ids):
    """
    Retrieve multiple emails using batch requests.
    It's recommended to use a maximum of 20 in a single call.
    """
    batch = self.service.new_batch_http_request()
    mails_map = {}
    def callback(request_id, response, exception):
        if exception is not None:
            print(f"Error occurred for {request_id}: {exception}")
        else:
            mail_id = response['id']
            mails_map[mail_id] = response
    for idx, msg_id in enumerate(ids):
        batch.add(self.service.users().messages().get(userId="me", id=msg_id), request_id=str(idx), callback=callback)
    batch.execute()
    return mails_map


Currently, it takes about 20 minutes to fetch 10,000 emails, which is quite slow. I can't fetch more than 20 emails at a time using batch requests, as it triggers rate limit errors. However, I can't find any specific rate limit values mentioned in the Gmail API documentation for batch requests.
Is there a way to increase the number of emails fetched in a single batch request without hitting the rate limits? Or is there a better approach to optimize this process and speed things up? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Google publishes quotas and limits for Gmail: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota

Each Gmail get request is 5 quota units (batch or individual). Your quota limit is 250 quota units per second. That means you can request up to 50 emails per second max and that cannot be increased. IIRC batch requests should not exceed 50 individual gets, but Google often imposes reduced rates via rate limiting. Google is more concerned with security than your application performance.

Note: each message.list will also cost 5 quota units. The default is 100 messages per list request and that will increase the total time and reduce your quota. If you are listing 10,000 messages, that will cost 500 quota units (two seconds of quota) which might affect the rate limit you are experiencing.

I did find this reference for Workspace Gmail: 100 per batch request: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch Free Gmail and paid Gmail are treated differently in some areas.

@JohnHanley
That's sound accurate. but whenever I'm batch request it more than 20 at a time it gives me rate limit error. Maybe that's because it's testing credentials? I can't see any information regarding the rate limits when using the test user credentials.

Also, the overall rate limit is interesting. I want to create Rest API that serve multiple users and I have no idea what will be the rate limit to fetch Emails metadata. I can't see information about it in their rate limit page.

You are approaching the issue with the wrong design. You must handle rate limiting, which means implementing Exponential backoff and retries. Google will decide what rate you can fetch requests and that can change over time. Do not try to get around that or determine absolute values.
